# Display Images from FTP server on android studio (JAVA)

Tags: java, android-studio, image-processing, ftp, imageview

I have an external camera support Capture photo and upload it on FTP server every 15s, also i have paid FTP Server from www.drivehq.com .

So, how i can display image from ftp server to my mobile app on android studio :

> (As you know every 15s there's a new photo uploaded on my ftp server) When i click CHECK button it will be show the new photo !

[image]

Comment: you need the url of the photo in order to display it via picasso ex: `www.drivehq.com/images/test-image.png` but to make it dynamic you need to have an API that send URL on your android that execute every 15 second to update your imageview.